# Custom LegendForm for MPAndroidChart PieChart

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

Currently the default supported `LegendForm` types are:

- `LegendForm.LINE`
- `LegendForm.CIRCLE`
- `LegendForm.SQUARE`

Is there a way to have something custom for the PieChart? Something like this:
http://s2.postimg.org/xhmy4stfd/Capture.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible by default. You will have to modify the library to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for this great library! WiIl you please direct me where in the library I can start fiddling?

Comment: Just override the LineChartRenderer and start from there